# Why is my reflection loading weird classes?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to play with reflection to see if I can get to a point where I'm able to type in a class name and my application will load that class and create an instance of it. After a few attempts I found I couldn't just stick a class name in `Class.forName()` without its package name, so I wound up trying to get a list of all available packages that have been loaded and trying to load the class I type in with each package name till it gets a hit.

This is what I've got so far:

```
BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = "";
    do
    {
        ClassLoader clsldr = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        Package[] pkgs = Package.getPackages();
        s = console.readLine();
        if(s.equals(":exit"))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        boolean classFound = false;
        Object loadedClass = null;
        String classname = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < pkgs.length; i++) {
            Package package1 = pkgs[i];
            try
            {
                classname = package1.getName().replace('/', '.') + "." + s;
                clsldr.loadClass(classname);
                loadedClass = Class.forName(classname);
                classFound = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
        System.out.println("LOADED A CLASS!!!!");
        System.out.println(classname);
        System.out.println(loadedClass);
    }
    while(s.length() == 0);
```

It semi works in a very weird way. For example when I type in "Object" at the prompt it somehow manages to load `sun.net.util.Object`, but when I print out the actual object it prints `class java.lang.Object`. I get the same thing with a `String` as well as several other things I typed. One interesting one I tried was `int` - it loaded `sun.net.util.int` and when I printed the object it just returned null. Another happened when I tried `Java`:

```
Java
LOADED A CLASS!!!!
sun.net.util.Java
null
```

Does anyone have any clue what's happening here? Is there something special about the `sun.net.util` package that's causing this? I don't really care that my code doesn't work exactly like I want, I would just love to know what's causing this strange behaviour.

Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"                                         
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)            
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I'm on Windows 8 64 bit if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought of something: I never break out of my loop when I fidnd a class. So this thing is probably actually managing to get to `java.lang.Object` which sets class loaded to true,  but it continues in the loop which overwrites the actual class that loaded, and `sun.net.util` is probably the last package loaded on my system. All I need is a break statement and it should stop this behaviour.

Comment: Except that that scheme will fail if the "weird" class is the one that appears first.  Or if neither of the classes is "weird"; e.g. `java.util.Date` versus `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is returning "weird" classes because what it is doing is conceptually broken.  There is nothing in any specification that says what the physical order of entries in the "rt.jar" file should be.  They just happen to be in an order that results in you finding the "weird" one given the way you are doing the iteration.  In another Java release, your code might give you the "non-weird" `Object` class.  Either way, the assumption that you will get the "right" class this way is ... flawed.

---

You say that you are doing this because:

> *"I wanted to take a stab at making a Java interpreter"*

Well if you are going to implement an interpreter, you need to understand the Java language.
And one of the things that you need to understand is that there can be *many* classes with the same simple name in Java.  This means that your idea of scanning the classpath for any class with a given simple name is simply not practical.  You will find that there are too many "collision" (i.e. classes with the same simple name) for commonly used classes.

In conventional Java, this collision problem is addressed by either referring to classes by their fully qualified names or by *importing* them.  For your interpreter to be usable, you need to implement an import scheme that mirrors conventional Java's import mechanism.

In short, ditch the code above and start again.

Comment: I was waiting for this answer :) like I said, this bit of code was just for experimentation, I have very little experience with reflection so I just wanted to get my feet wet. Also, my question was "why does this code load weird classes" and not "how can I fix it". Thanks for the tip though, I'll probably come around again asking for help with the import scheme :)

Comment: I have addressed the "why" part of your question.  (I didn't before because I thought it was redundant.  But since you insist ...)

Answer (score 0):

The classes starting with `sun` and `com.sun` are internal and mostly undocumented "housekeeping" classes used by the JVM internals. They're not part of the Java API, and different JVMs will have different ones. The fact that you're seeing all these different internals is the reason why you have to specify a fully-qualified name for the Reflection API. ;-)

Comment: I figured that... do you think it would be safe to ignore `sun.*` packages and `com.sun.*` to avoid this behaviour? Is there a better way to do a class/package lookup?

Comment: For what purpose? Just for experimentation? And you can't completely ignore `com.sun`, since some of those classes are regularly visible in normal operation, usually behind interfaces (implementations of crypto algorithms selected by a `String` lookup key, for example). The SCTP libraries, IIRC, are also in `com.sun` and used directly.

Comment: Yeah pretty much. I wanted to take a stab at making a Java interpreter :D

Comment: Try tearing apart BeanShell; you might find some interesting Easter eggs.

Comment: I had no idea BeanShell is open source... Cool!